# Update Manager Partitions

Tags: partitioning, updates

Perhaps this is completely stupid, but here's my inquiry:

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed on an external hard drive.  On that HD there are 4 partitions.  Two for operating systems, two for swap (unnecessary but I like it that way).

The actual computer itself has Windows 7.  If I use the Update manager to update to 12.10 or even 13.04, would the new Ubuntu install itself on the same partition it already was on?  The other operating system I'm running on the Hard Drive is Lubuntu, for when I need to run Linux on older computers, if that matters.

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wouldn't install, it would *upgrade*. It would retain the partition, download and install new versions of software, and upgrade the configuration scripts accordingly.